# Google API Quota on Google API place autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-api, python-requests, google-places-api

I working on an application I would like to use [Google API place autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform). It looks like every Google API has a limited use of,2 500 requests per day, even though this special API isn't mentioned in the following page [API Google Maps for Work](https://www.google.com/intx/fr/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html).

My question is :

How do they count requests with this API?

1. One letter = one request
2. One letter = many requests (one for each field in the list)
3. one request = a click on the list when the adress is complete
4. maybe a request is something else but i didn't find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Place Autocomplete Address Form](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) uses the Google Places API, it also uses the [Google Places JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places).

That being said if you check the Usage Limits and billing for the [Google places api web service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage) you will notice at the top it states.

> These limits do not apply to the Places JavaScript Library, which does
>   not require an API key, and is covered by the [Google Maps JavaScript
>   API limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage).

If you then follow the link over to the [Google Maps JavScript API v3 Usage limits and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) you will see it states.

> Most websites and applications may use the Google Maps API free of
>   charge. However, if you consistently generate a high amount of
>   traffic, usage limits apply and you will need to pay for extra usage.
>   **If your site or application generates 25 000 map loads** or more each
>   day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll get in touch with you to
>   talk about payment. Don’t worry, if you go over the limits, we won’t
>   immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your
>   site.

Google Places API doesn't load maps I suspect that there is no limit to how much you can use it.  I suspect that this is a public api, which has no limits. I believe this is true because the Places API doesn't require an API key if there is no API key Google really has no way of knowing who you. There will be no way of knowing that you send 1 or 10000 requests to the system other then maybe monitoring your ip address.   Even if they did monitor your IP address they would have no way of contacting you.

Comment: " The Place Autocomplete service is part of the Google Places API Web Service and shares an API key and quotas with the Google Places API Web Service. " This is what i found on google, this is why i'm hesitating, because i'm using the autocomplete without any other service at the moment, this is why i don't need an API key but still this sentence says i need one..; i don't wanna risk to pay :)

Comment: That statement is for if you are using the Google Places api yourself, not if you are using it though the Google Places JavaScript library.   Also remember Google cant and wont charge you anything until you agree to it. You don't need to use an API key with the JavaScript library there for there is no way they are going to be able to ask you to play.